# How to reduce if statements when the input parameter is array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I have a task to do where i have an array of days. I will have to print if the array includes specific days.The array can have any days in it as the user will decide what are the days they want to print.

```
 callDays(){
   
        const days: string[]=['Sunday','Monday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
        if(days.includes('Sunday')){
        console.log('Sunday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Monday')){
        console.log('Monday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Tuesday')){
        console.log('Tuesday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Wednesday')){
        console.log('Wednesday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Thursday')){
        console.log('Thursday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Friday')){
        console.log('Friday is included');
        }
        if(days.includes('Saturday')){
        console.log('Saturday is included');
        }
     }
```

In the above case Tuesday shouldn't get printed as it is not available in the array.
To do this task i had to use so many if statements. Is there a way i can do it without using this many if statements. Thank you.

Comment: How does the user decide, and how are those values used in the function?

Comment: That's what `includes` does anyway.: it loops over the array and compares each item to the value. Try to re-implement `includes` yourself and you will know what to do.

Comment: It seems probable that you only need the `javascript` tag here and not `java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```js
function callDays(days: string[]) {
   const POSSIBLE_DAYS: string[] = ['Sunday','Monday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

   days.forEach((day) => {
      if (POSSIBLE_DAYS.includes(day))
         console.log(`${day} is included`);
   });
}
```

A slightly more complicated implementation but will likely be faster is:

```js
function callDays(days: string[]) {
   const POSSIBLE_DAYS_SET: Set<string> = new Set(['Sunday','Monday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']);

   days.forEach((day) => {
      if (POSSIBLE_DAYS.has(day))
         console.log(`${day} is included`);
   });
}
```

**Edit**: For calling functions based off days in provided array

```
function sundayActivity() {}
function mondayActivity() {}
function tuesdayActivity() {}
function wednesdayActivity() {}
function thursdayActivity() {}
function fridayActivity() {}
function saturdayActivity() {}

const POSSIBLE_DAYS = {
  sunday: sundayActivity,
  monday: mondayActivity,
  tuesday: tuesdayActivity,
  wednesday: wednesdayActivity,
  thursday: thursdayActivity,
  friday: fridayActivity,
  saturday: saturdayActivity,
} as const

function callDays(days: string[]) {
  days.forEach((day) => {
    if (day.toLowerCase() in POSSIBLE_DAYS) 
      POSSIBLE_DAYS[day.toLowerCase()]()
  })
}
```

Comment: Of course if you want to make it more flexible, lowercase everything before comparing

Comment: Since you're in control of it, you may as well use a `Set` or just an object map for `POSSIBLE_DAYS` to make the lookups O(1)

Comment: @Danny Very fair, was trying to keep it simple considering the current attempt but its an edit I'll leave for others

Comment: I like this approach. I am curious,Instead of printing 'Sunday is included' 'Monday is included' and so on.. if i have to execute a certain function for certain days . How can i do that? Like days[]=['Sunday'] then sundayActivity() should be executed.How can i do it. Please reply. @Jack

Comment: @Danny Also technically the algorithm still is O(1) because the comparison is constant 

Comment: @pja Implementation would look pretty different. You would want to use an object map and map days to functions. For example, `let ACTIVITIES = { "Sunday": sundayActivity }`. Then, in the `forEach` you lookup `ACTIVITIES[day]`. If it exists, you call `ACTIVITIES[day]()`.

Comment: @Jack I think Array.includes() has a time complexity `O(n)`

Comment: @YakupMalikov It does, but in algorithm proofs, because we know n is static (# of items and characters in POSSIBLE_DAYS), it's treated as a constant and is O(1).

Comment: @Jack , i am new to javascript and typescript ,it would be grateful  if you could share a code snippet for that implementation. Thank you.

Comment: Done @pja. I would recommend writing this stuff yourself in general though as that's the only way to learn. Remember to mark the answer as correct if this is what you needed!

Comment: @Jack Thank you for the help, you are an angel.